# Error: attempt to apply non-function in a simple equation

Tags: r

I try to run this

```
pollution$log_mort <- pollution$log(mort)
```

But receive this error:

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

The mort vector contains numbers between 900 and 1100. What's wrong?

Comment: Would you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Have you searched base R help? It seems it's just that you're using the wrong basic syntax: you apply a function to a vector, what function are you trying to apply here (surely pollution$log is not a function...)

Comment: Assuming you have "mort" column, try: `pollution$log_mort <- log(pollution$mort)`

Comment: Yes, @zx8754 that did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to calculate the `log` of values in your vector. If so, this is how the `log()` function should be used:

```
pollution = data.frame(mort = 900:1100)
pollution$log_mort = log(pollution$mort)
pollution$log_mort
```

In case you prefer to use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
pollution = pollution %>%
        mutate(log_mort = log(mort))
pollution$log_mort
```

```
[1] 6.802395 6.803505 6.804615 6.805723 6.806829 6.807935 6.809039 6.810142 6.811244 6.812345 6.813445 6.814543 6.815640 6.816736 6.817831 6.818924
 [17] 6.820016 6.821107 6.822197 6.823286 6.824374 6.825460 6.826545 6.827629 6.828712 6.829794 6.830874 6.831954 6.833032 6.834109 6.835185 6.836259
 [33] 6.837333 6.838405 6.839476 6.840547 6.841615 6.842683 6.843750 6.844815 6.845880 6.846943 6.848005 6.849066 6.850126 6.851185 6.852243 6.853299
 [49] 6.854355 6.855409 6.856462 6.857514 6.858565 6.859615 6.860664 6.861711 6.862758 6.863803 6.864848 6.865891 6.866933 6.867974 6.869014 6.870053
 [65] 6.871091 6.872128 6.873164 6.874198 6.875232 6.876265 6.877296 6.878326 6.879356 6.880384 6.881411 6.882437 6.883463 6.884487 6.885510 6.886532
 [81] 6.887553 6.888572 6.889591 6.890609 6.891626 6.892642 6.893656 6.894670 6.895683 6.896694 6.897705 6.898715 6.899723 6.900731 6.901737 6.902743
 [97] 6.903747 6.904751 6.905753 6.906755 6.907755 6.908755 6.909753 6.910751 6.911747 6.912743 6.913737 6.914731 6.915723 6.916715 6.917706 6.918695
[113] 6.919684 6.920672 6.921658 6.922644 6.923629 6.924612 6.925595 6.926577 6.927558 6.928538 6.929517 6.930495 6.931472 6.932448 6.933423 6.934397
[129] 6.935370 6.936343 6.937314 6.938284 6.939254 6.940222 6.941190 6.942157 6.943122 6.944087 6.945051 6.946014 6.946976 6.947937 6.948897 6.949856
[145] 6.950815 6.951772 6.952729 6.953684 6.954639 6.955593 6.956545 6.957497 6.958448 6.959399 6.960348 6.961296 6.962243 6.963190 6.964136 6.965080
[161] 6.966024 6.966967 6.967909 6.968850 6.969791 6.970730 6.971669 6.972606 6.973543 6.974479 6.975414 6.976348 6.977281 6.978214 6.979145 6.980076
[177] 6.981006 6.981935 6.982863 6.983790 6.984716 6.985642 6.986566 6.987490 6.988413 6.989335 6.990257 6.991177 6.992096 6.993015 6.993933 6.994850
[193] 6.995766 6.996681 6.997596 6.998510 6.999422 7.000334 7.001246 7.002156 7.003065
```

Comment: Thaaanks! It was a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this fits your appetite

```
transform(
  pollution,
  log_mort = log(mort)
)
```